# Monostable circuit

Tags: monostable

Please, I need simplest possible monostable circuit (with like NE555, 74121, 74123 etc.) that will provide output like in this diagram .I am wanting to limit the time that the output is high irrespective of how long the input is high .Would a simple RCD differentiater do the trick?

[image]

Comment: Please define "simplest". Cheapest, smallest, fewest parts, ...?

Comment: The shortened pulses will be the tricky part.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Without the shortened pulses a wire would work.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I mean the first and fourth pulses in the diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this circuit design request should be pretty easy. 
Use a half of a dual non-retriggerable monostable multivibrator such as the Fairchild 74VHC221A. Connect it up like this:

[image]

The circuit will use the two states highlighted in the truth table.

Answer (score 3):

D1 may not be necessary; may already be present in internal circuit of AND gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMD0M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is also a good solution but I guess would require some input buffer with low resistance output and that would require extra components

Comment: Perhaps -- but the OP didn't have any other information about the system.

Answer (score 1):

This might work as well:

[image: Picture of circuit]

[Simulate circuit in Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2049.687244006919805%2071%205%2043%0AM%20848%20320%20896%20320%200%202.5%0A150%20768%20320%20848%20320%200%202%205%0Aw%20432%20416%20768%20416%200%0Aw%20768%20416%20768%20336%200%0Aw%20768%20304%20768%20224%200%0Aw%20768%20224%20720%20224%200%0A170%20240%20304%20224%20304%202%201.5%20300%202.5%200.2%0Av%20240%20304%20272%20304%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0AI%20272%20304%20304%20304%200%205%0AI%20304%20304%20336%20304%200%205%0Aw%20464%20304%20432%20304%200%0Aw%20432%20416%20432%20304%200%0Ag%20496%20352%20496%20368%200%0Ac%20608%20240%20608%20304%200%200.000001%201.4167688635197535%0Ar%20608%20240%20608%20176%200%2010000%0AR%20608%20176%20608%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20608%20240%20560%20272%200%0Aw%20608%20304%20560%20304%200%0Aw%20608%20240%20672%20240%200%0Af%20672%20240%20720%20240%200%201.5%0Ag%20720%20256%20720%20288%200%0Ar%20720%20224%20720%20176%200%2010000%0AR%20720%20176%20720%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Af%20496%20288%20560%20288%200%201.5%0Af%20464%20304%20496%20304%200%201.5%0Ar%20496%20288%20496%20176%200%2010000%0Aw%20496%20320%20496%20352%200%0Aw%20496%20352%20560%20352%200%0Aw%20560%20352%20560%20304%200%0Aw%20608%20176%20496%20176%200%0Aw%20336%20304%20432%20304%200%0Ab%20359%20248%20189%20255%200%0Ab%20356%20354%20363%20248%200%0Ab%20189%20350%20363%20357%200%0Ab%20183%20358%20190%20256%200%0Ax%20184%20428%20365%20431%200%2018%20This%20is%20just%20for%20creating%0Ax%20185%20455%20296%20458%200%2018%20the%20test%20signal%0Ax%20262%20384%20274%20387%200%2024%20%5E%0Ax%20265%20395%20271%20398%200%2024%20%7C%0Ao%2010%2064%200%2035%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%200%2064%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0A)